# HTTP requests from Next.js/React to ASP.NET fail due to CORS

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, next.js, cors

I have a Next.js/React frontend project which makes HTTP requests to my ASP.NET backend.

The issue I currently have is that these requests for some reason fail.

My backend is running on port 5000 and 5001:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5001
```

And my frontend is running on port 3000:

```
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
```

I have the following CORS configuration in my Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(opt =>
{
    opt.AddDefaultPolicy(config =>
    {
        config.AllowAnyHeader();
        config.AllowAnyMethod();
        config.AllowAnyOrigin();
    });
});

app.UseCors();
```

For example, a GET request to `https://localhost:5000/user` fails with "Response body is not available to scripts (Reason: CORS Failed)".

My backend is configured to use Firebase authentication for certain endpoints if that somehow can play a role in this. I am currently on a Windows 11 machine.

Everything has worked previously and my CORS setup remains unchanged since then so I am very confused. I would be very grateful for any pointers.

Comment: What does your browser's DevTool's Network tab show w.r.t. the CORS preflight request?

Comment: The preflight requests seem to fail too, OPTIONS https://localhost:5000/user also yields "Response body is not available to scripts (Reason: CORS Failed)"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It works for me now - it was not a code change.

I tried accessing the endpoint in question directly in Mozilla Firefox and landed on a SSL page akin to "unverified certificate/insecure page, are you sure you want to access?" whereto I pressed yes. I suspect that might have somehow done the trick.